# Regex add text to code

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to change value of  element in my tables. I have tousands of this. The code is

```
<td>350,19</td>
```

and i need to change it to

```
<td>350,19 &euro;</td>
```

Problem is that i don't know how to replace it with notepad++.
The find selection works with

```
 \d{0,3}+\,\d{2}
```

but replace doesnt work. When i put

```
\1 &euro; or $1 &euro;
```

it puts only

```
&euro; in <td></td>
```

How can i add euro sign to that code.

Comment: `(\d{0,3}+\,\d{2})` - The brackets tell notepad++ to capture and bind the matches to `\1`

Comment: if you have bash on your computer you can easily identify and replace patterns with the `sed` command

Comment: No need wrapping the whole pattern with capturing parentheses, use the appropriate backreference to the whole match.

Comment: You can replace it with $& &euro;